# Return array value straight from the function in PHP?

Tags: php

When I run this, it works: `$content = get_content(); echo $content['content'];` but when I run this `echo get_content()['content'];` I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'`

Is there a way around this? I can provide the actual `get_content()` function if that is necessary but thought I'd start here.

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @PatrickQ 5.3.29

Comment: Ah I see that it’s only from 5.4 and up. Close :)

Comment: @SeaBass  That's a big "Yikes!" there.  You should _not_ be using a version that old.  I won't lecture you on that though.  The flagged duplicate answers your question.

Comment: It’s actually on a dev server that I just re-opened, but you are right :) I’ll upgrade.

Comment: this works starting v5.4.0 [demo](https://3v4l.org/790VZ)